# How to change font type in twitter.com widget?

Tags: twitter, fonts, widget, styling

I have some basic knowledge in coding, most of which I learned through reading.

I'm using wordpress for my website. Now I like the official twitter widget but the only downside for it is the limited options of styling.

I've checked the available styling options, but couldn't find any which allows me to change the font size.

So I thought I'd try to import the javascript file ( here: http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js ) and see if I can change anything in it. So I searched for "font" and edited the default font in the file then uploaded it to my website, but it didn't affect how the font appears.

Is there a simple way to enforce changing the predefined css of the widget?

Answer (score 25):

The only solution I found with Twitter's Enhanced Timeline is to use javascript to modify the css after the iframe has loaded.

Needed to use window.setTimeout for it.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".e-entry-title").css("font-family","sans-serif");
    $(".twitter-timeline").contents().find(".tweet").css("font-family","sans-serif");
  }, 1000);
```

I'm not saying I'm "proud" of using setTimeout, but when my wife wants a styled Twitter's widget for her site, she GETS a styled Twitter widget.

Comment: :) Thanks, I used $(window).bind("load", function() { .. your code });

Comment: hahah "she GETS  a styled Twitter widget"

Answer (score 5):

> Twitter does not allow you to change font-size or font-family just with settings.
>
> you can't style content of an iframe originating on another domain
>   either.

**There seems to be a solution when you get the javascript files yourself like you say:**

http://www.petermoss.com/post/how-to-change-Twitter-widgets-font-size-or-color.aspx

To change the font of your tweets you have to change the following CSS class in widget.js (on your own server):

```
.twtr-tweet-text {
    font size: 105%;
    font-family: Georgia, Serif;
}
```

**Another possible solution is to implement the widget yourself using their JSON api:**

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

**Or use another third party widget like below**:

- http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/twitterjs/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks Nick. I think the solution you offered doesn't apply to the new twitter widget. Please refer to the javascript file (link in 1st post).

Any other suggestions?

I'd have loved to implement the widget myself but that's too advanced for me.

Comment: Then it is possible that it is not possible. You should actually use the first third party widget, that one is great and you can style it.

Comment: The link is broken, this is for anyone looking what was there: https://web.archive.org/web/20130430045913/http://www.petermoss.com/post/how-to-change-Twitter-widgets-font-size-or-color.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The font size will change if you limit the width of the widget. To get a smaller font size make the widget narrower.

Comment: Thanks, this is great advice. I wrapped the timeline link and script tags in a div with fixed width and it looks much better! `<div style="width:600px"><a class="twitter-timeline" ... ></div>`